# Detecting Objects with Opencv java

Tags: java, opencv, contour

I am trying to extract contours objects from this: [image]
Which is the S component of a HSV image obtained from this: [image]

My code:

```
Mat hsvImage = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, hsvImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
List<Mat> images = new ArrayList<>();
Core.split(hsvImage, images);

Mat blur = new Mat();
Imgproc.medianBlur(images.get(1), blur, 1);

Mat thresh = new Mat();
Imgproc.threshold(blur, thresh, 40, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
Imgproc.findContours(thresh, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, 
 Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);`
```

Results are not bad, but I need to improve detection.
I would like to remove image background, but I don't know if is possible and how. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Please insert images inside the question body instead of giving image link, because in some situation it is not opening.

Comment: I tried but it seems I am not allowed to embed images

Comment: It is what I get when I try to open the image link: `This site can’t be reached drive.google.com took too long to respond.`

Comment: I just tested all two links and seem working. May be it is a temporary issue on your side.

Comment: What object do you want extract from the original image?

Comment: I am interest to buildings